# Using Ajax with Jquery on a Node in Drupal 7

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, drupal-7

I'm very new to PHP/Drupal. The idea here is I'm trying to grab a dataset from an Energy Star API and transfer that information into a table I created using Ajax. On localhost this works perfectly using Jquery's GETJSON and appending the necessary information to the table with append().  When I try to do this in Drupal, however, nothing works.  There is no physical file for this page, it's just a node. I've included the Javascript and CSS pages to the page template with the necessary page path and I know the page can access both because I used Jquery to go between tabs and that works, but I can't get anything Ajax/renewing CSS with table to work.

Do I have to create a module and use a hook menu? I've seen that places but it doesn't seem right seeing that I only have the node to work with.

Thanks in advance!